# How to center tabs in bootstrap4?

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

I want to show my `login/Signup` tabs and their relative form in the middle of the page and also want to small textfileds like `col-md-12` to `col-md-4` but when I use `style="margin-left=200px;"` the form will be in the middle but in mobile mode it is not showing so I removed `style="margin-left=200px;"`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}

.form-signin input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <h4 class="text-center">User Panel</h4>
  <hr>
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs form-signin" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">SignUp</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <form class="form-signin">
        <img class="mb-4" src="https://camu.in/assets/img/avatar1.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <p>Signup</p>
      <form class="form-signin">
        <img class="mb-4" src="https://camu.in/assets/img/avatar1.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

I want to produce below output the tabs and form in the middle of the page but I am not able to do it. Kindly check below image what I want. Also when I click on `SignUp` everything is messed up.

[image]

Comment: Add the `justify-content-center` class to your `<ul>` and the tabs will be centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center the ul with the class-name `nav-tabs` by adding the class-name `justify-content-center`. Additionally, touch the active tab and the gray border by adding the class-name `pb-0` to the `nav-tabs`.

So, it is `<ul class="nav nav-tabs form-signin justify-content-center pb-0" role="tablist">` instead of `<ul class="nav nav-tabs form-signin" role="tablist">`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}

.form-signin input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h4 class="text-center">User Panel</h4>
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs form-signin justify-content-center pb-0" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">SignUp</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <form class="form-signin">
        <img class="mb-4" src="https://camu.in/assets/img/avatar1.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <form class="form-signin">
        <img class="mb-4" src="https://camu.in/assets/img/avatar1.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign up</h1>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: @ Razvan Zamfir, Thanks for the answer and the most important explanation in answer. The code is now working perfectly. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution using [justify-content-center](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content) on the  element.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3 justify-content-center">
```

Comment: @ Meir Roth  thanks for the answer. The tabs is in the middle now but when I click on signup tab the user panel text and below line will go up and the text will be gone "User Panel".

Answer (score 0):

Just use the bootstrap class `"justify-content-center"` in your  element as

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs form-signin justify-content-center" role="tablist">
```

link to the [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/tiqeday/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: @ Vikash.777  thanks for the answer. The tabs is in the middle now but when I click on signup tab the user panel text and below line will go up and the text will be gone "User Panel".